# hide shortcode using hooks

Tags: functions

Hi i'm trying to hide a shortcode using hooks, my shortcode is this [abc] 
I have use this code:

```
remove_shortcode( 'abc' );
```

this code above removes the shortcode but when i refresh the page
I can see the shortcode text [abc]

how can i hide the text [abc] using hooks?or

I'm using a hook function code, to hide the shortcode on a specific category. 
I cannot use css to hide this shortcode, because it will affect and hide the other category.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing the shortcode, re-register it with a function that returns an empty string (or something that casts to an empty string). You can use the built in [`__return_empty_string`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_return_empty_string). This will replace whatever the original callback was with something that just replaces the shortcode with nothing.

```
// sometime after the first call to add_shortcode
add_shortcode('abc', '__return_empty_string');
```

If you control the original shortcode function, adding a way to shortcircuit the shortcode and stop processing is a good way to go:

```
add_shortcode('abc', 'wpse205424_shortcode');
function wpse205424_shortcode($args)
{
  if (apply_filters('wpse205424_disable_shortcode', false)) {
    return '';
  }

  // rest of the shortcode as normal here.
}
```

Then somewhere else in your code you can check for the reason to disable the shortcode and hook into your filter.

```
if (shortcodeShouldBeDisabledForSomeReason()) {
  add_filter('wpse205424_disable_shortcode', '__return_true');
}
```

Comment: I am trying to diable the shortcode on plugin deativation with `register_deactivation_hook` how can i do that?